# GSON deserialize as array although JSON source is object

Tags: json, deserialization, gson

I'd like to deserialize this using GSON into a list of Post, but can't figure out how to tell GSON how to ignore the root element "posts" (as its an object) and just process the array.

I've got:

```
Type postTypeList = new TypeToken<List<Post>>(){}.getType();

JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(myJSONString);
JsonObject postsRootObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

List<Post> postList = gson.fromJson(postsRootObj.get("posts"), postTypeList);
```

BUT.. I'd rather not have the whole JsonParser, I'd rather just pass it directly into the gson.fromJson function..  Is there a way to do this?

```
{ "posts":
  [      

        {
       "username": "John",  
       "message": "I'm back",
       "time": "2010-5-6 7:00:34"
        "validator":[{
                        "prog": "Name1",
                        "name": "Name2",
                        "computername": "Name3",
                        "date": "2010-11-20 19:39:55"
                      }]
        }
      ,

        {
          "username": "Smith",
          "message": "I've been waiting",
          "time": "2010-4-6 10:30:26"
           "validator":[{
                        "prog": "Name1",
                        "name": "Name2",
                        "computername": "Name3",
                        "date": "2010-11-20 19:39:55"
                      }]

       }
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper class which will have `List<Post>` as its member

```
public class PostList{
private List<Post> posts;
// getter and setters for posts
}
```

And then use `fromJson` in the similar fashion

```
List<Post> postList = gson.fromJson(myJSONString,PostList.class);
```

Comment: This is the other approach I thought of, however in my opinion its an unnecessary class, I was just hoping something might have been built into GSON to assist with my problem.

Comment: Ohh okay! Hmmm..I could only think of this and the approach you wrote..Correct me if I'm wrong,but I don't think there will be any way to force `Gson` to completely ignore the root element..

Answer (score 0):

There is a correction from above. Usage should be :

```
 PostList postList = gson.fromJson(myJSONString,PostList.class);
 Post post = postlist.get(index) //index is the index of list you want to access
```